# how will one angular component tell another to refresh without manually refreshing whole page

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a node backend with firebase auth that connects to an angular frontend. I have two component that is the navbar and the register form, when I register I call a backend function to register in firebase and sent back the firebase.auth().currentUser, how should my angular frontend navbar detects the arrival of such user and updates itself accordingly, without me refresh the page?

Comment: you can use a shared state or `subscription` to achieve this

Comment: Not sure how this can be done with Agnular but in AngualarJS there is a hack, you just compile and link the component and then use JQLite to replace old component with the new one. (`angular.element('component').replaceWith($compile('<component></component>')($rootScope.$new()))`). But this a hack to just what you're asking, it's not solution, you should be able to do what you need with proper router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is how your components are structured:

```
// In app.component.html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>   // For rest of the pages.
```

Here, there are 2 ways (I'll not talk about including ngModel) by which we can pass data to navbar for updating the status/data of navbar.

**1. Using Input/Output decorators.**

```
// Your navbar.component.ts

// I'm assuming you have set up model for User. If no, then change the type to **any**.
@Input() currentUser: IUser;   

// Your navbar.component.html
<p *ngIf="currentUser"> {{currentUser | json}} </p>   // Render this if currentUser exists. By default, it is undefined.
```

Now, in your **App component**:

```
//In your app.component.ts

User: any | IUser;

public authenticateUser() {
 this.someServiceToAuthenticateUser.subscribe(
  res => this.User = res,    
  error => console.error(error)
);
}


 // In your app.component.html
<app-navbar [currentUser]="User"></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

2. **Using a common service.**
   You can create the common service which stores the authenticated user in it. From your **App component**, you can set the user on the success of authenticating the response and from other components, you can fetch the authenticated user.

```js
export class UserService {
 private currentUser: IUser | any;

 setCurrentUser(userToSet: any) {
    this.currentUser = userToSet;
}

getCurrentUser() {
 return this.currentUser;
}
```

Now, in your **App component**, if the request for authenticating the use is a success, then set the currentUser of UserService:

```
//In your app.component.ts

User: any | IUser;

public authenticateUser() {
 this.someServiceToAuthenticateUser.subscribe(
  res => this.UserService.setCurrentUser(res),    
  error => console.error(error)
);
}
```

Now, in your **navbar component**, get the current user from UserService.

```
// In navbar.component.ts

 currentUser: any;

constructor(private userServicce: UserService) {
 getuserFromservice();
}

 public getuserFromservice() {
 setInterval(() => {
  curretnUser = this.userService.getCurrentUser()
}, 3000);
```

**Important:** In this approach, notice in navbar component, I have set the current user in setInterval. This is because your **getuserFromservice()** will run only once (when it is created/rendered for the first time) and at this time, userService will have no currentUser. So navbar will never get the currenUser.
If you want to replace the setInterval approach (I highly encourage to replace it), then use **Subjects/BehaviourSubject/ReplaySubject**. I did not include them here because **Rxjs** is a huge topic in itself and including it would be too much to understand here.

Answer (score 0):

**Input & Output operator is good but It can't provide flexibility of sharing data like observable**

Here You need to use Subject Observable to share data among the app. It's very easy and useful thing. You can send signal to all the lisner when user is registered.

What you need to do

1) **Create one service file to share data**
   - service have subject observable. Using that you can subscribe the channel for user data

2) **In the your header component listener that service and set the listener coming data to header user data**

3) From your register, Profile update,or anywhere else user data was update, just past that data to **subject observable it will automatically update user in entire app**. follow below example to achieve this

**You can find the working demo in below link**

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject